# MPMoviePlayerController with URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, media-player

I know this Question may be asked before . But I didn't find the solution for my case .
I am trying to play a video by `MPMoviePlayerController`. I can play a local video. But the problem is how to play video from its internet `URL`.
I have searched for the answer. And I know I should use `initWithContentURL` method . but that doesn't help me. the video appear black.

> I am sure that my `URL` is a `link` for the video itself.

**Here is my code**

```
 moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]  initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<MY video URL>"]];


// video player scalling
moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

// Set the frame for the  video player view
moviePlayerController.view.frame =CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height*3/5);
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
```

Comment: First: `[NSURL URLWithString:@"<MY video URL>"]` is `null`? Else, what's the extension of the URL? Does `MPMoviePlayerController` plays it directly? You may have to do some work on that URL before, or maybe it just can't play that kind of content.

Comment: There are more than 20 question asked on this issue, you must do some research before asking .

Comment: @Larme The video extension is "3gp", I tried to play this video extension from by a local video , it played successfully

Comment: @Vizllx I have searched for the answer and . and find no solution. I have considered all these answers but didn't find the answer 
I mentioned that this is may be a duplicate question above . Thanks for your info .

Comment: What have you tried so far that is not working, I can see a basic logic error , you are missing [player play]  ? Have u tried to catch MPMoviePlayerLoadState notification , I cannot see anywhere in your question? What you have debugged so far? So it's shows your lack of research.

Answer (score -1):

You need to mention movie source type as streaming.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpvc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                 selector:@selector(moviePlaybackDidFinish:)
                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                   object:nil];    

mpvc.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mpvc];
[mpvc.moviePlayer play];
```